# Set title and add button to navigation controller

Tags: objective-c

I created a navigation controller but i can not set title or add button to the navigation bar.How to do that?
This is the code of application DidFinishLauchingOption in file AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.view;
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `rootViewController` property of your window object to the navigation controller, rather than your instance of `ViewController. This should point you in the right direction:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create and configure a window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Create a view controller
    UIViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    // Create a navigation controller and set its root view controller to the instance of `ViewController`
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    // Add the navigation controller to the window
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// ...

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the view controller's title
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"View Controller", @"");

    // Add a navigation bar button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonPressed:)];
}

- (void)refreshButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Do something when the refresh button is pressed.
}

// ...

@end
```

Comment: It do not work. And all the things i put into my viewcontroller do not appear. :(

Answer (score 0):

To create your initial setup, you create a navigation controller with your view controller and set it as the root view controller of your app delegate window:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //create window
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];

    //create and set root view controller
    [[self window] setRootViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[RootViewController alloc] init]]];

    //make window key and visible
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //bail
    return YES;
}
```

Then in your view controller, set the title and add your navigation item:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //call parent implementation
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //set view controller title
    [self setTitle:@"Root View Controller"];

    //add navigation bar button
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(handleBarButtonItemEvents:)]];
}
```

And listen for button events via:

```
- (void)handleBarButtonItemEvents:(id)sender
{
    //
}
```